# Modifying skimage's 'try_all_threshold' function

Tags: python, scikit-image, image-thresholding

I am currently working with the ***try_all_threshold*** function that comes with the skimage filters package (skimage.filters.try_all_threshold).

It applies 8 types of thresholding methods on an image and then plots these 8 generated thresholds next to each other. However, there are way more thresholding methods described in the skimage documentation, and I am currently trying to find a way of modifying the *try_all_threshold* function in a way that I could either add or exchange the thresholding methods that it usually applies, with alternative ones from the scikit environment.

For example: Instead of using the *skimage.filters.threshold_li* method, I would want to use the *skimage.filters.threshold_multiotsu* method in the *try_all_threshold* function. And ideally, I would want to also use more than 8 threshold methods at the same time to get a better overview, but I dont know if that is possible.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

Thank you all very much for your help and a good day!

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the function is here:

https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/v0.19.0/skimage/filters/thresholding.py#L97-L154

And you can see that it calls a private `_try_all` function here:

https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/812e21e44129258d8637fbcf665e590556ea96d1/skimage/filters/thresholding.py#L35

`try_all_threshold` is too inflexible (this should be improved) for you to modify a call to that function to do what you like, but you can copy the code and modify either function to add your preferred thresholding methods. Note that `multiotsu` is fundamentally different because it returns multiple threshold values, so you can't do `image > threshold_multiotsu(image)`; instead you have to do `np.digitize(image, threshold_multiotsu(image))`.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks very much for your help on this question too. Coming back from christmas break now managed to implement the suggestions. Have a good day!